# C# PCM data audio player for Silverlight 5

Tags: c#, pcm, playback, silverlight-5.0

Is there a way in SilverLight 5 to play PCM data?  This could be obtained from a stream from a web Server or obtained by reading a WAV file.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Silverlight 5 includes a class from the XNA Framework, namely `Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio`. This contains a type `SoundEffect` which you can use to play PCM data. (Since SL5 includes the class, I don't think you'll need to add any additional references)

```
var myAudioStream = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("PCMSound.wav", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
SoundEffect effect = SoundEffect.FromStream(myAudioStream);
effect.Play();
```

There are overloads for the `Play` method which you can see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.audio.soundeffect.play.aspx). One thing to note is that there are limitations in terms of the types of `wav` files you can use:

> Files must be PCM Encoded, 8 or 16 bit
>   mono or stereo and either 22.5khz,
>   44.1khz or 48khz sample rates.